# Groovy Spring DSL: constructing beans with properties of other beans

Tags: spring, grails

I have a bunch of Spring beans some of which need to be initialized from other beans, and some of which need to be initialized from properties of those other beans. E.g.:

```
Foo {
}

Bar {
    String getBaz()
}

Qux {
    Qux(Foo foo, String baz)
}
```

I thought I could write something like

```
beans = {
    foo(Foo) {}
    bar(Bar) {}
    qux(Qux, ref('foo'), ref('bar').baz) {}
}
```

but obviously this doesn't work because `ref('bar')` isn't Bar, it's a `RuntimeBeanReference`.

In plain Spring (3+) what I want is apparently possible with [spring expressions](http://www.enigmastation.com/2010/04/07/java-surgery-spring-injection-of-other-beans-properties/) but I can't figure out the necessary syntax with the Grails Spring DSL. Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant the classes to look like this:

```
class Foo {
}

class Bar {
   String baz
}

class Qux {
   Foo foo
   String baz

   Qux(Foo f, String b) {
      foo = f
      baz = b
   }
}
```

and the 2nd `ref('foo')` should have been `ref('bar')`. Then this will work:

```
beans = {
   foo(Foo)
   bar(Bar) {
      baz = 'wazzup'
   }
   qux(Qux, ref('foo'), '#{bar.baz}')
}
```

Comment: Burt, does this work only for constructors? I tried `bean(MyService){ prop = '#{anotherBean.foo()}' }` but did not work, null pointer.